# A column widget there all children match biggest widget width

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a widget that does not have width constraints, so it depends on the biggest child, all other children should match the same width.

I know I can not achieve that with `Row` inside `Column`, because Column does not have a bounded width.

The result which I am trying to achieve in the red circle: [image]

Comment: What did you try and what is the result?

Comment: Do you want to get the result as in the image or this is the one you are currently getting and trying to correct.

Comment: I wanted result as in image. Anyway thank you everyone, solved it with `IntrinsicWidth` as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046776/1533112

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positioning/Sizing a widget depending of the position/size of another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991872/positioning-sizing-a-widget-depending-of-the-position-size-of-another-widget)